# different approaches to implementing program counter

Tags: verilog, ise, spartan-6

I want to implement the following 32 bit program counter circuit:
[image]

and this is my current verilog code:

```
module program_counter(
     d,inc,ld,clr,
    clk,Q
);

input [31:0] d;
input inc,ld,clr,clk;
output reg [31:0] Q;

reg [31:0 ] q_inter;

always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (clr)
        q_inter = 32'b0;
    else if (ld)    begin
        case (inc)
            1'b0 : q_inter = d;
            1'b1 : q_inter = q_inter + 4;
    endcase
    end 
    Q = q_inter;
end


endmodule
```

I switched the assignments to blocking assignments because I wanted to wait for the q_inter to receive the updated signal before assigning it to Q, as I noticed that if they were non-blocking then it would result in delayed response in simulation.

I was initially trying to do the same thing by changing the q port to an inout port and doing something like this:

```
module program_counter(
     d,inc,ld,clr,
    clk,Q
);

input [31:0] d;
input inc,ld,clr,clk;
inout reg [31:0] Q;


always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (clr)
        Q = 32'b0;
    else if (ld)    begin
        case (inc)
            1'b0 : Q = d;
            1'b1 : Q = Q + 4;
        endcase
    end 
end


endmodule
```

but it gives me the following error:
"Non-net port Q cannot be of mode inout"

My questions:

1) Can anyone explain why making Q an inout give me this error?

2) Will changing the the assignments from blocking to non-blocking result in lower timing constraints? in other words, will it translate to a less-delayed circuit?

Comment: Why are you trying to make Q an inout when it's clearly an output? Could you post that delayed response you are talking about?

Comment: 1/ Always use non-blocking assignments in a clocked section. 2/ If your always increment by four, you can drop the LS 2 bits.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev - the delayed response is due to the fact that there are two registers... by default, q_inter will update in one cycle, then q will update in the next cycle.  Using blocking assignment makes them both update at the same time, thus making having the second one pointles...

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't match your schematic. With two separate `reg`s for `q_inter` and `Q`, what you've created is the circuit below (omitting the `clr` and `ld` signals for clarity):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fesKb0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But you don't need an `inout` for this either. (`inout reg` is a contradiction -- a `reg` drives a value, making it an `output` almost by definition.) All you need to do is either remove `q_internal`, replacing it with `Q`, or make `q_internal` a `wire` and assign it a value in a separate combinational block.

Comment: Except the blocking assignment means that Q updates *after* q_inter *but aligned to the same clock pulse*.  Which I doubt can be synthesised usefully by most tools (there are basically two approaches I can see: ignore the way the output value is specified to be generated with two registers and just connect  the mux output to Q's input directly, which is counterintuitive but probably the best you're likely to get, or introduce a delayed clock signal so that Q can update after q_inter, which seems an unlikely approach for an automatic tool to take).

Comment: I see my mistake now. I mistakenly made q_inter a reg when i meant for it to be a wire.